# QGIS heatmap not showing in plugin administrator

Tags: heatmap, qgis

I am trying to create a heatmap in QGIS, and most guides suggests using the heatmap plugin. The only problem is that it is not showing up in my QGIS installation. Do you have any suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

SOLVED:
Apparantly in the new version of QGIS, you just go to the properties of your points, and then you can do a heatmap there under styles.

[image]